# Error activating tensorflow virtual environment

Tags: bash, tensorflow, ubuntu, environment-variables

I couldn't activate TensorFlow env on Ubuntu(16.04 LTS) bash

I have tried "activate tensorflow" and source "activate tensorflow", but it did not work

"activate tensorflow" and
"source activate tensorflow" not working

I expect this : (tensorflow)$

but I'am getting this:

```
"activate tensorflow" display: /home/user/anaconda3/bin/activate: 5: /home/user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/etc/conda/activate.d/activate-binutils_linux-64.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

while "source activate tensorflow" displays nothing, though my TensorFlow environment is active.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try creating a virtual environment using command in terminal `virtualenv myenv`. If virtualenv is not installed then install it using `pip install virtualenv` and run the above mentioned command again.

After creating it, open it using `source myenv/bin/activate`. Now you must be in the environment. If you see `(myenv)` on the left side in terminal then yes you are. 
Now install TF using `pip install tensorflow` and you are good to go.

Comment: i am using conda not pip. "source myenv/bin/activate" displays "no such file or directory exist"

Answer (score 0):

How about these three steps?

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev python-virtualenv
```

```
$ virtualenv --system-site-packages ~/tensorflow
```

```
$ source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate
```